# iphone scrollview does not shift down with its superview when a calling bar appears on top of iPhone

Tags: iphone, scrollview

I've just noticed on my iPhone app that if I do these steps:
1. call someone with my iPhone
2. press home button to take call app to background (without hanging the call)
3. open my iPhone app
In this case my app's window is shifted down a little to place under the appeared bar, but the scrollview inside the app is not shifted down correspondingly and is messed with its superview content.
Is this a bug or I should do something to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK I've found out how to do.
I've used **UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin** and **UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight** for the scrollview and now it moves down when needed.